# Symfony 2.3.4 Implemented form not validated

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have user model + user type, register model + register type... When i Execute it id doesn't validate user (inner data) model. Code below...

User model:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Serializable;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\MainBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @return array|\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\Role[]
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array($this->id));
    }

    /**
     * @param string $serialized
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list ($this->id,) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = false;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="User name cannot be blank.")
     */
    private $username;

    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->username = $userName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Password cannot be blank.")
     */
    private $password;

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $salt;

    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="E-Mail cannot be blank.")
     * @Assert\Email(message="Invalid email address.")
     */
    private $email;

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

}
```

User Type:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'User name'))
            ->add(
                'password',
                'repeated',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'first_name' => 'password',
                    'second_name' => 'confirm',
                    'type' => 'password'
                )
            )
            ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'E-Mail'));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Site\MainBundle\Entity\User',
                'required' => false
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'main_user';
    }
}
```

Register model:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Site\MainBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Register
 */
class Register
{
    /**
     * @var Site\MainBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="Site\MainBundle\Entity\User")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="No terms accepted.")
     * @Assert\True(message="You have to accept terms to be registered.")
     */
    protected $terms;

    public function setTerms($terms)
    {
        $this->terms = (Boolean)$terms;

        return $this;

    }

    public function getTerms()
    {
        return $this->terms;
    }
}
```

Register Type:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Site\MainBundle\Form\UserType;

class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', new UserType())
            ->add('terms', 'checkbox');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Site\MainBundle\Entity\Register',
                'required' => false
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'main_register';
    }
}
```

And controller with twig. Part of twig:

```
{% block page_content %}

    <form method="post" action="{{ path('main_register') }}">
        {{ form_errors(formRegister.user.username) }}
        {{ form_row(formRegister.user.username) }}

        {{ form_errors(formRegister.user.password.password) }}
        {{ form_row(formRegister.user.password.password) }}

        {{ form_errors(formRegister.user.password.confirm) }}
        {{ form_row(formRegister.user.password.confirm) }}

        {{ form_errors(formRegister.user.email) }}
        {{ form_row(formRegister.user.email) }}

        {{ form_errors(formRegister.terms) }}
        {{ form_row(formRegister.terms) }}

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Register Controller:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Site\MainBundle\Form\RegisterType;
use Site\MainBundle\Entity\Register;

/**
 * RegisterController
 */
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function defaultAction()
    {
        $formRegister = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), new Register());

        if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('post')) {
            $formRegister->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

            if ($formRegister->isValid()) {
                echo 'form is valid';
            }
        }


        $twig = 'SiteMainBundle:register:default.html.twig';
        $data = array(
            'formRegister' => $formRegister->createView()
        );

        return $this->render($twig, $data);
    }
}
```

Where can be problem? Help please with it.

**Updated**

```
echo "<pre>";
echo $formRegister->getErrorsAsString();
echo '</pre>';
```

says:

```
user:
    username:
        No errors
    password:
        password:
            No errors
        confirm:
            No errors
    email:
        No errors
terms:
    ERROR: No terms accepted.
    ERROR: You have to accept terms to be registered.
```

As you can see model User is not validated AT ALL... =\

Comment: BTW i did everything that was said in manual at symfony2 dot com =\

Comment: Also, project was created by composer as "standard project".

Comment: `When i Execute it id doesn't validate user (inner data) model` What do you mean?

Comment: I mean validation doesn't work. It reacts on 'unchecked' terms but on empty fields of username\password\email not. So there are NO errors on all fields (except terms).

Comment: So what you mean is that the validation is effective only for the `terms` field (which is a checkbox) but the other fields are not validated (so they always pass validation, even when empty)?

Comment: Yes they are. And I can't get where mistake and why it do this way... =\

Comment: I did everything as said in official manual. Here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html for sf2.3 version

Comment: `$formRegister->isValid()` is `true` even without the email or you don't see the error message on the view?

Comment: yes, $formRegister->isValid() is true even without the email

Comment: regarding code, if I will check terms - form will show me 'form is valid', but other fields is empty

Comment: Hmm. Is there anyone actually reading all this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, finally.
Bug is in this part. I wanted to disable this way browser validation...

```
'required' => false
```

BUT. This "guys" (I mean developers),compare two things in one setting. So if we set 'required' to false our fields won't be validated. And if true it will be validate BUT ALSO WITH browser validator.. =\ Maybe someone know how to avoid it (browser validation) NOT by editing twig file (some options or other setting)?

PS: To avoid browser i changed twig.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('main_register') }}" novalidate>
```

Comment: You can also use: `{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'novalidate': 'novalidate'} }) }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it by code, in your Controller, your code should be like:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function defaultAction()
    {
        $formRegister = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), new Register(), array(
            'attr'=> array('novalidate'=>'novalidate'),
        ));
```

With the therd parámeter of "createForm", you can modified the form (for example: acction, class, etc).

I normaly use:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistroType(), $usuario, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('jgo_registro'),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'attr'=> array('novalidate'=>'novalidate'),
));
```